# Contour lines are somewhat square-ish?

Tags: qgis, contour

I am exporting contour lines from a raster file which was obtained by clipping a shapefile to a much larger raster file. **The contour lines obtained are square-ish as in the second image below.**

My first attempt in generating contour lines looks like this. The lines are smooth enough. [image: first attempt of generating contour lines]

And my second attempt looks like the image below. Lines are squared as if they are following an invisible grid. [image: second attempt of generating contour lines]

First time I didn't really pay attention to what I was doing and followed a tutorial or two.
Second time I discovered that projection matters and fiddled with it :). Second screenshot is in ESPG:27700 projection (if this matters, I don't know).
**Did you see this before and if yes, how do I fix this?** If not, can you point me please in the right direction? What to read, or to what this issue might be related to.
My guess is that when I am clipping, resolution is lost. But then how did I manage to obtain smooth lines first time?

Comment: can you add some details about the raster you used and how you reprojected it to EPSG:27700

Comment: The rasters are from JAXA's AW3D30 DSM. They are coming in tiles of 1x1 degree. 
I merged 4 of those tiles and saved the resulted raster in order to select a suitable projection. On that raster, I clipped the shape of the area I am interested in.

Answer (score 3):

What I was doing wrong: trying to change the projection via Layer Properties > Source > Set source coordinate system. This produced a square-ish-looking output (both on raster and vector).
What worked for me (tested on a raster layer): from the top bar select Raster > Projections > Warp and the result wasn't square-ish anymore.